# What should be the standard for country tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags

We already have quite a lot of country-tags by now. Given enough time we will likely end up with tags for pretty much every country in the world. For that reason I think it would make sense to set a guideline what information the tag excerpt (usage guideline) and the tag wiki article of a country should contain.

Here are some examples what we already got:

> a [government form] in [geographical region]

Examples: [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)[ukraine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine)[australia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia)

> for questions about [country]

Examples: [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)[india](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india)

Regarding tag articles, there does not seem to exist any discernible pattern yet.

What do you think should be the standard?

Comment: I don't think any of your examples is particularly useful. Tag wikis are there to provide usage guidance, not definitions of commonly used terms. There's some (admittedly vague) guidance on writing tag wikis here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/

Answer (score 2):

Country tags should list the formal name of the country and possibly, for lesser-known countries, a general geographic location.

For instance, I created [republic-of-georgia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republic-of-georgia) with this excerpt

> Questions related to the eastern European country of Georgia, which borders Russia.

The geographic location helps, especially when you don't know where places like [romania](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romania) are.